# Python loop benchmark with timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I would like to benchmark a specific code segment inside a for loop in Python. I am using `timeit` as follows:

```
def createTokens():
    keypath=('./pickles/key.pickle')
    path="./data/"
    directory = os.listdir(path)
    tok={}
    print('create tokens..')
    t=[2**4,2**5,2**6,2**7,2**8,2**9,2**10,2**12,2**14,2**16]
    files=['pl_10000004','pl_10000002','pl_100000026']
    for filename in files:
        for i in t:
            code='etok=utils.token(filename,keypath,str(i))'
            t = timeit.Timer(stmt=code,setup='from __main__ import utils')
            print(filename+'_'+str(i)+'.pickle')
            print ('%f'%float(t.timeit(10/10)))
```

However this raises:

```
NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined
```

when I include filename in setup variable Python says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name filename
```

How is this is solved?

Comment: how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filename` isn't defined in the scope of the code in the `timeit` block. I don't know what `utils` is in your code, but assuming it expects `filename` and `keypath` as strings just replace your

```
    code='etok=utils.token(filename,keypath,str(i))'
```

line with:

```
    code='etok=utils.token("{}","{}",{})'.format(filename, keypath, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
code='etok=utils.token("%s","%s","%s")' % (filename, keypath, i)
```

This will allow you to create a code string that has the values you want. Also, by using the `%s` conversion, `i` is coerced into a `str` type for you.

**Edit:** Added double quotes around values.

Comment: I am getting errors with the respect to the values assigned to  the variables: `NameError: global name 'pl_10000004' is not defined`. pl_10000004 is the first assignment of filename var in the loop

Comment: You need to add quotes around the string insertion points. I.e. `utils.token("%s","%s",%s)`.

Comment: @FamousJameous: Thanks. That's what I get for not testing this in an interpreter.